# javafx authorization and authentication concept

Tags: security, javafx-8

Could somebody advice me the best solution about JavaFX (JDK8) and security concept? Under security I mean authorization and authentication. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question is too broad for this forum: there are many ways to implement security and the choice of how you do it depends, to some degree, on how you implement your business tier and data tier. Additionally, JavaFX is a toolkit for implementing the user interface tier: it has nothing to do with security.

Comment: "it has nothing to do with security" - this is what I'm afraid (( I'm looking for some solution how to show at the same Scene, for example, for different users another content.

Comment: You're missing the point. It's not the job of the UI to perform security checks, it's the job of the business tier. So this is not implemented by JavaFX, it's implemented by other Java libraries. You implement the security using, say, JAAS, and then the UI shows the appropriate view depending on the results of that.

Comment: Hi James_D, you are right, this is business layer responsibility. I've user SpringSecurity and it works almost like I expected.

Answer (score 0):

I might be a bit late in answering this, but you are very right Maryan. JavaFx doesn't seem to have good interoperability with any standard security mechanisms. 
The only option is to use a 3PP to solve this. Examples are: Spring security, Apache Shiro etc. In order to eliminate the dependencies with a particular 3PP, I encourage you to wrap the 3PP implementation.

Unfortunately, This is just the beginning of a long list of issues(that are yet to come up) for you, even after you implement the security measure, you will still have to come up with ways of storing and managing security tokens(similar to browser cookies) so that your JavaFx client doesn't need to authenticate with server for every call.
If this is only the beginning of your project, I suggest you really think about whether to use JavaFx or go with web based UI.